# How do i get the value of span class

Tags: jquery, html, class

I want to take values from the span classes..

**My html code is**

```
<span class="font18">Rs.360</span>
<span class="font18">Rs.1000</span>
```

I have separate buttons for each amount. If i click the amount it shows the current amount..

**Jquery code is**

```
function sms_confirm() {
       var r = confirm("Confirm the order to buy " + $("span[class='font']").text() + " Amount")

       if (r == false) {
           return false;
       }

   }
```

The result is showing empty values.. How to take the values?

Comment: Its `font18`, not `font`. And you have 2 elements with that class, which one are you expecting to see?

Comment: Also you don't need to do `class='font'`. Just do `span.font`

Comment: I have separate buttons for each span class amount(rs.360, rs.1000).when i click the button it alerts the value of current amount.

Comment: @Duk see my demo http://jsfiddle.net/6UEnN/

Comment: thanks. ya i saw. here working good. i want to show the button click.. when i change this code to button click it is showing undefined amount.. My button code is <a href="<%: Url.Action("Payment", "EmployerVas") %>"><img src="../../Content/Images/Subscribe now on click.png" class="btn" onclick="return sms_confirm()"/></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you go ahead .[Perfect Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6UEnN/)

```
$(".font18").click(function () {
    var clickedClass = $(this).text();

    function sms_confirm(clickedClass) {
        var r = confirm("Confirm the order to buy " + clickedClass + " Amount");

        if (r === false) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    sms_confirm(clickedClass);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(".font18").text();
```

as class name is `font18` not just `font`.

Or you can modify your code to get the attribute class starts with like:

```
$("span[class^='font']").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to match font*

```
$("span[class^='font']").text()
```

Or to match exactly the `font18` class then

```
$("span.font18").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `jquery ^` to check for `start with`

Then find the value of span whose classes starts with font

**`$('span[class^="font"]').text();`**